# I want to show tier prices to specific customers of Valid Vat ID group magento 2.4.6

Tags: customer, customer-account, magento2.4.6, module-development, taxvat

I have magento 2.4.6. I have Enabled Automatic Assignment to Customer Group.
Group for Valid VAT ID - Domestic is B2B0% (which means 0 tax)
Group for Invalid VAT ID- B2B21% (which means 21tax).
I have configured these everything is working fine.

Now i have tier prices for few products which i am showing to customer specific group "wholesale".

I want its working like below.

1. if vat ID is valid and customer group is whole sale then show tier price.
2. if vat id is valid and customer group is not whole sale then price exl vat will be shown.
3. if vat is invalid then show price inl tax.

Im not able to achieve point 1.
how can i do this. I'm stuck here.